# Library Hashids import in vue.js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, hashids

I can't seem to get the library [hashids](https://hashids.org/) to work with vue.js

The preferend method of how i want to work with it is:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        {{ hashids.encode('1') }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
const Hashids = require("hashids")

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            Hashids: Hashids,
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried `{{ Hashids.encode('1') }}` ??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just tried it. It returns the error "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.Hashids.encode is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize the `Hashid` in mounted hook like :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        {{ Hashids.encode('1') }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  const Hashids = require("hashids")

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        Hashids: null,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.Hashids = new Hashids.default()
    }

  }
</script>
```

This made it work!

Comment: It wil say: "TypeError: Hashids is not a constructor". Maybe the "const Hashids = require("hashids")" part is wrong?

Comment: @WoutervanErp did `new Hashids.default()` fix the issue?